# Getting info from associated tables

Tags: sequelize.js

I have two tables:

```
---id---userid--- and ---id---productid---productname---
```

So, it is associated by the following code:

```
Product.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'resultingproducts', foreignKey: 'userid'});
User.belongsToMany(Product, {through: 'resultingproducts', foreignKey: 'productid'});
```

I've tried to get products from "Product" for current user

```
        Product.sync()
        .then(() => {
            Product.findAll({
                include: [User],
                through: {
                    where: {
                        userid: userId
                }
        })
```

but this code returns products for all users in db.
Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really be querying on User model rather than Products model.
Try changing your code to following to find all products 'related' to 'this' user.

```
User.findAll({
  include: {
    model: Product, // Product is Product model
    through: {attributes: []} // this will remove rows from join table in the result
  },
  where: { userId: userId } // note, where clause is outside 'include' and 'through'
})
```